# Can hashcode collision affect equals in Java?

Tags: java

The `hashCode()` contract allows different objects to have the same hash code. From the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> It is **not required** that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

At the same time, in Eclipse, if use function Source->Generate hashCode() and equals, you will get some thing like this:

```
package test1;

public class j1 {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + a;
        result = prime * result + b;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //compare hashcode
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        j1 other = (j1) obj;
        if (a != other.a)
            return false;
        if (b != other.b)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

In function equals(), we first compare hashcode of `this` and `obj`, if they have same hashcode, then equals() returns true. But the document says that two different objects may have different hashcode, which will affect the correctness of `equals()`. I just can't figure out this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In function equals(), we first compare hashcode of this and obj, if they have same hashcode, then equals() returns true.

No, `if (this == obj)` **does not** compare the hash code of two objects. It checks whether `this` and `obj` are referring to the same `Object`, in which case they must also be equal (since any `Object` should be equal to itself), so all the following logic of `equals` doesn't need to be executed in this case.

On the other hand, if `this != obj`, `this` and `obj` are referring to different `Object`s, but may still be equal to each other, depending on the logic of `equals`. If the logic of `equals` returns `true`, the contract requires that they must have the same `hashCode()`.

Comment: I just misunderstand hashcode and ==, thank you for this clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

The call on `this == obs` does not compare the hashcode. It compares the reference of the object. Basically checking if you use it like this

`this.equals(this)` which is true.